# reusable message Symfony Messanger library

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

does anyone know what to do when I use the messanger.yaml package for communication in symfony and I want the sent message to be reusable?

What do I mean by multiple use?

- the point is that when I send a message for a particular queue, I would like the same message to appear every message:consume, because currently, because after making message:consume, the message disappears from the queue, I would ask for help

Answer (score 0):

After a message is consumed it's normally removed from the queue it was in (as typically you just want to process sequentially all the messages you have in the queue and delete them). If you have multiple consumers pointing to that queue, the first consumer processing will get it and then the message will be removed, which means all other consumers will not get the messages.

Think it this way: if you don't delete the messages from the queue, your consumers will be looping over them again and again.

However, as a workaround, you can create multiple queues (one for each consumer you have) and define the exchange to work in 'fanout' mode, that means, everytime a message is sent through the defined transport, it will be sent to every queue defined in its exchange.

Here is an example of the configuration:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            transportname:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: messages
                        type: fanout
                    queues:
                        queue1: ~
                        queue2: ~
        routing:
            'App\Message\MessageNotification': transportname
```

Comment: your consumers will be looping over them again and again. ofcourse thank for help.